# Prompt before closing MAUI / Blazor hybrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

I've created a MAUI / Blazor hybrid app, following this guide here https://www.telerik.com/blogs/sharing-code-blazor-dotnet-maui and everything works fine so far.

In my app saving needs to be done manually (and I don't want to save automatically aswell), so I'm looking for some way to show a prompt before closing the app when there are unsaved changes.

When the app is running in the browser, I think this shoud be no problem but I struggle to archive that within MAUI. I'm able to detect when the app is closing but I can't prevent it or abort it.

Is there any way to do this in MAUI or do I have to find another solution?

Comment: There is some useful information about the app lifecycle here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @KonradPsiuk this is what I found aswell and what I'm using to detect when the app closes/stopps but as fas as I can tell it does not say anywhere how to prevent a closed or stopped event

Comment: You cannot prevent the closing of an app, at least not in mobile environments. AFAIK, iOS and Android don't allow it for security reasons mainly, but also because it wouldn't be in line with user experience guidelines.

Comment: how would I solve this problem then within the user guidelines? saving the current state when the application is closed and restore it when opening again? I think this would be technically possible atleast

Comment: Yes, that is a possible and common approach in mobile apps. You can use the `OnSleep()` and `OnResume()` overrides for this, for example. You could, for example, set a flag in the app's `Preferences` that let's you know if you auto-saved and if the previous state should be restored in the `OnSleep()` override. Then you check for that flag during the app start as well as in the `OnResume()` override. Once restored or after a manual save, you need to remove/unset the flag and only set it again if the user didn't manually save the state.

Comment: There isn't a way to prevent the user from exiting or aborting the app. You should save the changes and allow the user to revert them rather than requiring an active prompt to save.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, app closing is handled by the system but perhaps You can implement some logic by overriding Application methods:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    
    
    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        base.OnSleep();
    }
}
```